# Tirar Caracteres de Fundo

Tags: eclipse

Gostaria de saber como faço para tirar os caracteres de fundo do eclipse como esta na imagem!!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Clique com o botao direito no codigo, vá em  Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors. Tem um checkbox chamado "Show whitespace characters". Se voce desmarcar este checkbox vai voltar ao normal.

Se voce clicar no link "configure visibility" vai aparecer uma janela, que voce pode definir quais caracteres o Eclipse deve mostrar.

Comment: Blz... hahahahaha.. valeu Mesmo!!!

Comment: =) não esquece de aceitar a resposta....